# Reading a user credentials from file concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I came across the following code snippet:

```
static private volatile ConfigUserCredentails maintenanceUserCred = null;
static private Object maintenanceUserLock = new Object();

/**
 * This method is slower.  Recommend use the one from cache.  
 *
 * @return The username/password credentials of the maintenance user.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static ConfigUserCredentails getMaintenanceUserCredentials() throws IOException {
    return readCredentialsFromFile(MAINTENANCE_CREDENTIALS_PROPS, Crypt.getDefaultCrypt());
}

/**
 * 
 * @return The username/password credentials of the maintenance user.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static ConfigUserCredentails getMaintenanceUserCredentialsFromCache() throws IOException {
    if (maintenanceUserCred != null) {
        return maintenanceUserCred;
    }
    synchronized(maintenanceUserLock) {
        if (maintenanceUserCred == null) {
            maintenanceUserCred = getMaintenanceUserCredentials();
        }
    }
    return maintenanceUserCred;
}
```

'getMaintenanceUserCredentials()' just reads the user credentials from file and
creates new user object.

My questions are:

1. What is the purpose of 'volatile'?
2. Why would one need the 'synchronized' block?

Thanks,
Rafik

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question does not match what this site is about. One of our requirements for questions is: "**Authorship of code**: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that [...] the poster know why the code is written the way it is." Have a look at our [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When a variable is `volatile`, then the code that access that variable is forced to read/write the value of variable from/to the memory. Without `volatile`, the value of variable can be (temporarily) stored to place (like register/cache) where changes are not immediately visible to other threads, or changes by other threads are not immediately visible.
2. `synchronized` is used in the code for avoiding concurrent and duplicate initialization of `maintenanceUserCred`. Without the `synchronized` block, two or more threads can enter to `maintenanceUserCred = getMaintenanceUserCredentials();` line at the same time. The `synchronized` will pass only one thread at a time to the block, so `maintenanceUserCred = getMaintenanceUserCredentials();` will be done only once.

Both `synchronized` and `volatile` will create memory barriers, that ensures that loads and stores are really from/to the main memory (not only local cache of current CPU core).

For example without `volatile` and `synchronized` the generated code could *effectively* work like the following code:

```
ConfigUserCredentails tmp = maintenanceUserCred;

if (tmp != null) {
    return tmp;
}
tmp = getMaintenanceUserCredentials();
maintenanceUserCred = tmp;
return tmp;
```

That will allow several threads to call getMaintenanceUserCredentials() at the same time and threads may obtain different ConfigUserCredentails objects.